# Pass a url query string containing double quotes to API Gateway ? encodeURI not working

Tags: json, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am making an http request to an API gateway wrapping a lambda.
I have a query string parameter which is like this :

```
LG - 50" Class (49.5" Diag.) - LED - 2160p - Smart - 4K Ultra HD TV - Black
```

I tried to encodeURIComponent and pass it to my http request call. I get this error

```
 body: '{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\\\'C\\\' (code 67)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\\n at [Source: [B@5ebb26a9; line: 1, column: 28]"}' }
```

If I remove the double quotes it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is thrown while your Lambda function tries to parse it. Can you check API Gateway's CloudWatch logs (easy to check in test invoke console) to make sure that the "Endpoint request body after transformations" is as your Lambda function expects?